# Calculating the smallest sum of a list where certain subsets have different values

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, set, subset

I am trying to recreate the card game "Five Crowns" in python and I ran into a tricky algorithmic problem I can't figure out for trying to calculate the score of a hand. Basically, scoring works like this:

> As in the game Three Thirteen, players create sets or runs of 3 or more, using the Jokers and the current round's wild card as wilds. Each round has a different wild card (the 3's in the 3-card hand, 4's in the 4-card hand, 5's in the 5-card hand, and so on until the King is wild in the 13-card hand).

More info -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Crowns_(game)

Each set  of 3 or more is worth 0 points, each run of 3 or more is worth 0 points and your score is the sum of the values of the cards in your hand. (Ace (1) to King (13) and unused jokers (50))

```
e.g. with a hand of [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11]

 - The wild card is 6
 - Score would be 18
    - Run of 1, 6, 3, 4 = 0 
    - 7
    - 11
```

```
e.g. with a hand of [2, 2, 8, 11, 12, 13, 50, 50]

 - The wild card is 8
 - Score would be 0
   - Run of 8, 11, 12, 13 = 0 
   - Set of 2, 2, 50, 50 = 0
```

I have no idea how to go about this problem. Are there any similar algorithms out there?

All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: The article says after a player layed down all of his cards all other players get one turn before the game finishes (including drawing and discarding a card), so the easiest way to do this is to force the players to lay down their cards in the last round (or tell you how they are matched), so you just need to sum up the remaining/unmatched cards.

Comment: @maraca the end goal was to have a single player game so the CPU hands would have to be calculated